# How to reset a form including any validation errors?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, jquery-validate

I 'm trying to reset a form in my Yii project with

```
$form.reset();
```

This way I can only manage to reset fields values, but existing validation errors are still showing. How can I also clear validation errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii installs hooks for this functionality, but it doesn't expose them conveniently. To reset the form completely you need to do:

```
$form.reset().trigger('reset');
```