# Reset a form in Yii using JS

Tags: php, yii

I tried using jquery method.

```
$('#contact-form')[0].reset();
```

Not working.

I tried the following to reset the form.

```
$form->reset();
```

It gives the following error.

"reset() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given"

and i added "form id" to reset like bellow

```
$form->reset("contact-form");
```

Its not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at source, form reset set defaults values of elements, not empty. Look at default values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset a form including any validation errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283755/how-to-reset-a-form-including-any-validation-errors)

Comment: @Sergey First of all thanks. Yes the values i entered are set to default value after submit. I reset the values using emptying the field values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I reset the form. It happens because after submitting the form entered value are set to default in every fields. To reset the field values we need to empty the default values.

Ex.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#id_of_the_textbox').val("");//using the id of the textbox empty the value.
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have the problem exactly in that "form values are set to default after submit". Do you know how can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is an old post but thought i should add an answer.

### Yii2

The Best way to reset a form when using `js`, like if you are submitting the form via ajax and after receiving the successful response you want to clear the form with the validation messages, you should use `resetFrom` function  of `Activeform` js like below

```
$("#form-id").yiiActiveForm('resetForm');
```

To remove the values from the form inputs you should use the following way

```
$("#form-id")[0].reset()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @BudiMulyo using select2 or any similar 3rd party plugin is an exception as it creates custom HTML to build the select2, the above post refers to the default form elements. you can use `$("#your_select_inpt_id").val('').trigger('change')`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php echo CHtml::resetButton('Reset'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to reset a form try this

```
$('#contact-form').reset().trigger('reset');// if id of your form is "contact-form"
```

Comment: I tried this also. but it is not working.. I also tried to add a html reset button. Before i submitting the form the reset button is working. after i submit when click the reset button it is not working..